# Simple Server using netcat and curl

Tags: bash, curl, netcat

I am trying to build a simple server with netcat and curl.

netcat gets data coming from a port and then runs a curl command as follows to send the data to a webservice.

```
nc -l -k 2233 | while read x ; do curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"DATA": `echo $x` }' https://example.com/FEP ; done
```

for some reason, the `echo $x` is not being evaluated to the read value.

Comment: the '$x' is not expanding inside of single quotes...

Comment: nopes it is not expanding that is the main problem maybe i was not clear enough.

Comment: And I told you the problem source. Any bash `$variable` is not expands in the single quotes. ;)

Comment: @ghili yes, that is what jm666 is saying. You need to move `$x` out of the `'` delimited string, e.g. `-d '{"DATA":"'$x'" }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move $x out of the `'` delimited string, e.g. `-d '{"DATA":"'$x'" }'`.

Special characters in single quoted strings are never honored.

Answer (score 0):

See the example:

```
x=text

echo single: '$x'
echo double: "$x"
```

prints

```
single: $x
double: text
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to echo `$x`; just use

```
curl [options] '{"DATA": '$x' }' https://example.com/FEP; done
```